# udev - am i using it, where do i see it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, udev

It is mentioned that udev present devices in /dev for devices that are presented to the kernel and it is use to create persistent naming.

I have having 2 harddisk

/dev/sda

/dev/sdb.

How does udev keep their naming persistent ? I check through the rule.d further and I don't see any relevant or rules pertaining to the disk.

> [root@SJOAM rules.d]# ls -l total 44
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1652 Nov 12  2010 60-fprint-autosuspend.rules
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1060 Nov 12  2010 60-pcmcia.rule
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  316 Oct 15  2014 60-raw.rule
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  789 Jan 25 00:25 70-persistent-cd.rule
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  756 Jan 24 23:22 70-persistent-net.rule
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  320 Jan 12 21:17 90-alsa.rules
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   83 Oct 15  2014 90-hal.rules
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2486 Nov 11  2010 97-bluetooth-serial.rules
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  308 Apr 15 18:46 98-kexec.rules
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   54 Dec  8  2011 99-fuse.rules

It is also mentioned that inside the /dev/disk/by-* are all actually symbolic links created by udev.
But where do can i see the rules ?

[root@SJOAM rules.d]# cd /dev/disk/by-
by-id/    by-label/ by-path/  by-uuid/

Regards,
Noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, which I understand you have available, in the directory */etc/udev/rules.d*, there is a *README* file which states:

> package-supplied rules ... can be found in /lib/udev/rules.d ...

So, now

```
# ls -lhd /lib/udev/rules.d/*disk*
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8,0K giu 10 18:58 /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10K mar 10  2014 /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules
```

and there you are. I bet on Centos (which I do not use) you can do likewise.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae thanks, indeed they are there
[root@centos1 rules.d]# ls *disk*
13-dm-disk.rules  80-udisks.rules , i am using centos, not sure why i am not able to find them as specified by Yitzchak

Answer (score 0):

In centOS, they're in `/etc/udev/rules.d/*disk*`, at least on my system. I am [given to understand](https://serverfault.com/a/646513/72860) that RHEL-style distros no longer use udev by default.